# Play 2.3 package JPA is missing

Tags: hibernate, jpa, playframework, package

I work with play 2.3.6 and JPA ORM to the data, so i follow the documentation of playframework (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaJPA) but i don't know why the package play.db.jpa is not imported into my project.

I try to clean my project (activator clean, activator clean-files) but nothing changed

What it miss to work fine ???

below is my configuration :

**build.sbt**

```
name := "play_sample1"

version := "1.0"


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(  
  javaJdbc,  
  cache,
  javaWs,
  javaJpa,
  "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.6.Final",  
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayJava) 
                    .aggregate(common, webstats)  
                    .dependsOn(common, webstats)                 

lazy val core = (project in file("modules/core")).enablePlugins(PlayJava)

lazy val common = (project in file("modules/common")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).dependsOn(core)
lazy val webstats = (project in file("modules/webstats")).enablePlugins(PlayJava).dependsOn(common)
```

**appplication.conf**

```
# This is the main configuration file for the application.
# ~~~~~

# Secret key
# ~~~~~
# The secret key is used to secure cryptographics functions.
#
# This must be changed for production, but we recommend not changing it in this file.
#
# See http://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/ApplicationSecret for more details.
application.secret="yIX1uonulRO^O8A56tlkb1c4aJS^@9k<dr@^mDXuSBXggKHMRJykv@>``Ra?yh<i"

# The application languages
# ~~~~~
application.langs="en"

# Global object class
# ~~~~~
# Define the Global object class for this application.
# Default to Global in the root package.
# application.global=Global

# Router
# ~~~~~
# Define the Router object to use for this application.
# This router will be looked up first when the application is starting up,
# so make sure this is the entry point.
# Furthermore, it's assumed your route file is named properly.
# So for an application router like `conf/my.application.Router`,
# you may need to define a router file `my.application.routes`.
# Default to Routes in the root package (and `conf/routes`)
# application.router=my.application.Routes

# Database configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many datasources as you want.
# By convention, the default datasource is named `default`

db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/play_test"
db.default.user=root
db.default.password=""

jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS

# You can expose this datasource via JNDI if needed (Useful for JPA)
# db.default.jndiName=play_test

# Evolutions
# ~~~~~
# You can disable evolutions if needed
# evolutionplugin=disabled

# Ebean configuration
# ~~~~~
# You can declare as many Ebean servers as you want.
# By convention, the default server is named `default`
#
# ebean.default="models.*"

# Logger
# ~~~~~
# You can also configure logback (http://logback.qos.ch/),
# by providing an application-logger.xml file in the conf directory.

# Root logger:
logger.root=ERROR

# Logger used by the framework:
logger.play=INFO

# Logger provided to your application:
logger.application=DEBUG
```

**/conf/META-INF/persistence.xml**

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"  
version="2.0">  
  <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">  
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>  
    <properties>  
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />  
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"></property>
    </properties>  
  </persistence-unit>  
</persistence>
```

Comment: You need to add JPA, hibernate and mysql as a dependency of the subproject using them and not in the top proejct. So in your case if you use `JPA.em()` in core and common you need to add that as a dependency in core/build.sbt (as common depends on core it is not needed there). The same should apply to the xml files...

Comment: try moving `javaJpa` after `javaJdbc` then `activator clean` then try to import

Answer (score 0):

Try Removing the **javaJdbc** dependency.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I already tried to remove the javaJdbc but no changing. I've solved my problem by creating a new project with the same configuration file above. The package are not missing